# Generate Randomly placed images with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to place 5 images randomly on a div called "`leftSide`" with `width` & `height` `'500px'`
the `img` has `width` & `height` '`100px`' so I'm trying to generate the 5 images in the a range where it fits in the div.

I think this is all the relevant code:

```
numberOfFaces = 5
var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");
while (numberOfFaces > 0) {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = "smile.png";
    valueTop = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);
    valueL = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);
    img.style.top = valueTop + 'px';
    img.style.left = valueL + 'px';
    theLeftSide.appendChild(img);
    numberOfFaces -= 1;
```

I'd appreciate any idea's what I could be doing wrong and how to fix it. 
Thanks!
This should be solved without any libraries like jQuery

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: no image gets generated...
debugger says, TypeError: theLeftSide is null

Comment: The problem is in another part of code. Somewhere, where you try to work with `theLeftSide`.

Comment: sorry, I changed that for posting, theLeftSide is just document.getElementById('leftSide') to use theLeftSide in front of .appendChild(img) instead of the whole line. 
the only other place leftSide is mentioned is as an id in my <div> tag in the <body> of my html.
Edited.

Comment: Your error is quite explicit : there is no element with id "leftSide" to be found. Maybe did you make a typo in your HTML?

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I put the code in the <head> so it had not read the <div> tag by the time the code went through. Nina solved it now thought!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add

```
img.style.position = 'absolute';
```

for every inserted image.

And for the `leftSide` this:

```
<div id="leftSide" style="position: relative;">...
```

```js
var numberOfFaces = 5;
while (numberOfFaces--) {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = "http://lorempixel.com/50/50/cats/" + numberOfFaces;
    var valueTop = Math.random() * 400 | 0;
    var valueL = Math.random() * 400 | 0;
    img.style.top = valueTop + 'px';
    img.style.left = valueL + 'px';
    img.style.backgroundColor = '#0000ff';
    img.title = 'left: ' + valueL + ' top: ' + valueTop;
    img.style.position = 'absolute'; // <--------------------------------------- add this!
    document.getElementById('leftSide').appendChild(img);
}
```

```html
<div id="leftSide" style="position: relative; padding: 0; border: 0; width: 500px; height: 500px; background-color: #ffff00;">
```

Comment: Added, but I still don't get any img. 
I already put the style rules for div in my <head> under <style>

Comment: @Bizarre, it should not go to the div, but to the img in the while loop, like above.

Comment: yes I added that in the loop.
I'm talking about the last line of code you added. 
<div id="leftSide" style="width: 500px; height: 500px; background-color: #ffff00;">

Comment: Yes actually! just no source for the image...which is normal. Thanks Nina, still any idea why does my code not run the the image? it's in the same folder, name is correct... Even if I copy the exact code you wrote to my texteditor, save the file in the same folder as the image and run it there is no sign of any img.

Comment: maybe it has something to do with not writing its width and height? 
If I add it directly in html I would do: 
<img src="smile.png" alt="smile" width="100" height="100" />
In this case it's not specified anywhere...

Comment: the img size is taken from the img itself, but you can specify this.

Comment: please have a look to the changes. i added `position: relative;` to the div and changed the img style to absolute.

Comment: Yes I did that all of that... 
I copied your exact code with the extra things added, but there is still no added img... debugger says TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Comment: @Bizarre, `document.getElementById(...)` what is in the parenthesis? maybe a good idea is to move the code to the end of the page, maybe the div is not known before.

Comment: Wow!!!! That did it!!! Thank you Nina!
I messed up then putting the code in the head, had no idea that would create a problem!

Answer (score 0):

This is how i have done.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var imgCre, postop, posleft,posTopArray=[],posLeftArray=[];
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    postop = Math.floor((Math.random() * 400) + 1);
    posleft = Math.floor((Math.random() * 400) + 1);
    posTopArray[i] = postop;
    posLeftArray[i]= posleft;
     for(var j= 0;j<i;j++){
       
       if(posTopArray[j]==postop)
         postop = Math.floor((Math.random() * 400) + 1);//new random position if any of old position match with new
         
     }
    imgCre = "<img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/' style='width:100px; height:100px; position:absolute; top:" + postop + "px; left:" + posleft + "px'>";
    $("#imaggeContainer").append(imgCre);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #555;
}
#imaggeContainer {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 5px solid #f9d899;
  background-color: #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="imaggeContainer">
  <div>
```